# Target element within clicked div only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have formatted an API response to list certain properties as below.
When a users clicks on a `delete` link on a certain list item, I need to take the `taskID` from that item and be able to use it in `completeTask()`.
At present, no matter which list-item I click the `delete` link in - I always get the `taskID` of the first in the list.
How should I target `taskID` of **only** the list item upon which the `delete` was clicked ? 
**API call:**

```
axios({
            method: 'GET',
            auth: {
                username: APIKey,
                password: ':xxx'
            },
            url: 'https://apiExaple.json',
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $(response.data['todo-items']).each(function () {
                var taskID = this.id;
                var taskTitle = this.content;
                $(resultElement).append(
                    '<div class="taskDiv">' +
                        '<li style="list-style-type: none">' +
                            '<p>' + taskTitle + '</p >' +
                            '<p id="taskIDListItem">' + taskID + '</p>' +
                            '<p><a href="#" id="deleteBtn">Delete</a>' + '<a href="#" onclick="completeTask()" id="completeBtn"> | Complete | </a></p>' +
                        '</li>' + '<hr>' +
                    '</div>');
                //console.log('Task ID is: ' + taskID);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
        });
```

---

**Function which uses obtained taskID:**

```
function completeTask() {
    var task_id = this.$("#taskIDListItem").text();
    console.log(task_id);

    axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'https://apiExaple.json',
            auth: {
                username: APIKey,
                password: ':xxx'
            },                
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.statusText);    
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.statusText);
        })

}
```

---

**HTML for API response**

```
<!-- All Tasks -->
<div class="allTasks">
   <h4 class="h4-well-title">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i> Tasks
      <span>
         <h6 id="todaysDate"></h6>
      </span>
   </h4>
   <hr>
   <div class="panel-body" id="getAllTasksResult">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML

Comment: Plus the part where you listen for the click event. Also, beware multiple of the same ID; your initial code snippet suggests you might end up with multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: The problem is that you can’t have multiple elements in HTML with the same ID. The ID must be unique.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the multiple same ID's - was a typo from earlier. Not the cause, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onclick attribute like this

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
axios({
            method: 'GET',
            auth: {
                username: APIKey,
                password: ':xxx'
            },
            url: 'https://apiExaple.json',
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $(response.data['todo-items']).each(function () {
                var taskID = this.id;
                var taskTitle = this.content;
                $(resultElement).append(
                    '<div class="taskDiv">' +
                        '<li style="list-style-type: none">' +
                            '<p>' + taskTitle + '</p >' +
                            '<p  id="taskIDListItem">' + taskID + '</p>' +
                            '<p><a href="#" id="deleteBtn'+ taskID +'">Delete</a>' + '<a href="#" onclick="completeTask('+ taskID +')" id="completeBtn"> | Complete | </a></p>' +
                        '</li>' + '<hr>' +
                    '</div>');
                //console.log('Task ID is: ' + taskID);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
        });
        
        
function completeTask(task_id) {
    console.log(task_id);

    axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'https://apiExaple.json',
            auth: {
                username: APIKey,
                password: ':xxx'
            },                
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.statusText);    
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.statusText);
        })

}
```

plus you cannot use the same id multiple times you can concatenate it with taskID  like I did in deleteBtn

Comment: Thanks, but the log returns `undefined`